# What is オレたちゃ a contraction of?

Tags: translation, meaning, suffixes, contractions

I came across this line of dialgue, and I'm wondering what the lengthened version would be. For context, the series is in the middle of a tournamet (there are teams, but players compete individually), and one player has just witnessed another player winning their match with incredible skill. The spectating player thinks:

> オレたちゃここまでだな

I've translated that as 'We're finished/this is it for us', going on the assumption that オレたちゃ is a contracted of オレたち and another word.

Could someone tell me exactly what the long form of 'オレたちゃ' is? Or am I wrong and is 'たちゃ' another word entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's contracted with the particle は:

> オレた**ち＋は**　→　オレた**ちゃ**